# how do i implementing this array to hold data from a form

Tags: php, arrays, forms, arraylist

Iv been trying to send information from a form to my array so it can hold that information and display it when its needed. iv already managed to send the data from one page and echo it on another but i want it to be stored in a array so and display multiple problems at once. I was told to use this style of array to get the job done by a friend (see my array code below to get an idea) but it gives my a syntax error, iv tried different types of array's but i always get a syntax error.

My cart code (contains my array)

```
  <?php
  session_start();
  ?>


  <?php
  require_once("head.php");
  ?>
  <?php
  require_once("nav.php");
  ?>




    <link id='stylecss' type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/cartstyle.css">
    <link id='stylecss' type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Shopping Cart </title>
    <div class="shopping-cart">
    <!-- Title -->
    <div class="title">
      Shopping Cart
    </div>

   <?php
  if(!isset($_SESSION['Array'])) {
  (
  Array
  (
       [got] => Array
        (
            [id] => MO1
            [option]
              [qty]
              [price]
    )

       [friends] => Array
          (
              [id] => MO2
            [option] 
            [qty]
              [price]
      )

       [inception] => Array
        (
            [id] => MO3
            [option] 
            [qty]
            [price]
      )

  )
  )
  }
  ?>

    <?php
    var_dump ($_POST);
    echo $_POST['option'];
    echo $_POST['id'];
    echo 'x';
    echo $_POST['qty'];
    ?>

  <script>
  $('.like-btn').on('click', function() {
     $(this).toggleClass('is-active');
  });
  </script>

  <script>
  $('.minus-btn').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $this = $(this);
      var $input = $this.closest('div').find('input');
      var value = parseInt($input.val());

      if (value &amp;gt; 1) {
          value = value - 1;
      } else {
          value = 0;
      }

    $input.val(value);

  });

  $('.plus-btn').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $this = $(this);
      var $input = $this.closest('div').find('input');
      var value = parseInt($input.val());

      if (value &amp;lt; 100) {
          value = value + 1;
      } else {
          value =100;
      }

      $input.val(value);
  });


  </script>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <?php
  require_once("footer.php");
  ?>
```

and my product code (my form in here):

```
<div class="color">
<?php
session_start();
?>


    <!-- Keep wireframe.css for debugging, add your css to style.css -->
    <link id='wireframecss' type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../wireframe.css" disabled>
    <link id='stylecss' type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src='../wireframe.js'></script>



    <?php
$title = "WatchFlix";
$style="css/style.css";
/*include is a php fuction which place all codes(php, html) at the location where the include statement is placed.*/
?>
<?php
include("head.php")
?>
<?php
include("nav.php")
?>


<?php
$movie = array("got"=>"Game of Thrones: Season 1", "frd"=>"Friends: Season 1", "incp"=>"Inception");
?>


<main class="row">
<div class="column">
<img class="moviephoto" src="gotimage.jpg" alt="friends"/> <br>
<div class="bmove">
<form action="cart.php" method="post">
Game of thrones season 1
   <input type = "hidden" name = "id" value = "M01" />
   <br>
  <select name="option">
  <option value="HD">HD</option>
  <option value="Full HD">Full HD</option>
  <option value="Blu-ray">Blu-ray</option>
</select>
<div class="widthc">
   <button class="prod" id="minus">−</button>
<input type="number" name="qty" value="0" id="qty" min="0" max="15"/>
<button class="prod" id="plus">+</button>
<br><br>
<button class="prod" type="submit"> Submit</button>
   </form>
   </div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="column">
<h2 class="movieheading"> Game of Thrones </h2>



<div class="rating">
<h4> Rating: <span style ="font-weight:normal;">MA 15+</span></h4>
</div>
<br>

<div class="release">
<h4> Release Date: <span style ="font-weight:normal;">17 April 2011</span> </h4>
</div>
<br>

<div class="cast">
<h4> Cast: <span style ="font-weight:normal;">Peter Dinklage, Lena Headey, Emilia Clarke, Kit Harington, Sophie Turner, Maisie Williams</span></h4>
</div>
<br>

<div class="category">
<h4> Category: <span style ="font-weight:normal;"> Action/Adventure/Drama/Fantasy/Romance </span> </h4>
</div>
<br>

<div class="moviedetail">
<h4>T.V Show Details:</h4>

<p>Years after a rebellion spurred by a stolen bride to be and the blind ambitions of a mad king, Robert of the house Baratheon sits on 
the much desired Iron Throne. In the mythical land of Westeros, nine noble families fight for every inch of control and every drop 
of power. The King's Hand, Jon Arryn, is dead. And Robert seeks out his only other ally in all of Westeros, his childhood friend 
Eddard Stark. The solemn and honorable Warden of the North is tasked to depart his frozen sanctuary and join the King in the 
capital of King's Landing to help the now overweight and drunk Robert rule. However, a letter in the dead of night informs Ned 
that the former Hand was murdered, and that Robert will be next. So noble Ned goes against his better desires in an attempt to 
save his friend and the kingdoms. But political intrigue, plots, murders, and sexual desires lead to a secret that could tear the 
Seven Kingdoms apart. And soon Eddard will find out what happens when you play the Game of Thrones.</p>
</div>


<div class="column">

</div>



<br><br><br>

</main>




 <script>
const minusButton = document.getElementById('minus');
const plusButton = document.getElementById('plus');
const inputField = document.getElementById('qty');
var currentValue = 0;

minusButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  currentValue = Number(inputField.value) >> 0;
  currentValue = currentValue - 1;
  if (currentValue < inputField.min) {
    inputField.value = inputField.min;
  } else {
    inputField.value = currentValue;
  }
});

plusButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  currentValue = Number(inputField.value) >> 0;
  currentValue = currentValue + 1;
  if (currentValue > inputField.max) {
    inputField.value = inputField.max;
  } else {
    inputField.value = currentValue;
  }
});
</script>

<br><br><br>

<?php
include("footer.php")
?>
</div>
```

Comment: That is not how you define an array in code. Please go read up on some basics first of all: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: @misorude im trying to hold multiple values for one object, like object 1 has a id, price and qty, then object 2/3/4 will have the same, and the values for price/qty are enterted in through the form then echo'd

Answer (score 0):

as i answerd in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52699100/how-can-i-write-an-array-that-holds-multiple-values-for-each-product) you must define an array with the specified structure but your syntax is not correct.
you must use in the following structure:

```
movieList[0][name] = 'got';
movieList[0][id] = 'MO1';
movieList[0][option][qty]=2;
movieList[0][option][price]=20;

movieList[1][name] = 'friends';
movieList[1][id] = 'MO2';
movieList[1][option][qty]=2;
movieList[1][option][price]=20;

movieList[2][name] = 'inception';
movieList[2][id] = 'MO3';
movieList[2][option][qty]=5;
movieList[2][option][price]=30;
```