# How can i write an array that holds multiple values for each product

Tags: php, html, arrays, arraylist

I've been searching around php.net, w3schools and youtube for something that has multiple objects like "move1, movie2" where each of those objects has variables like `"id, qty, price"`.

I prefer an array were I can leave the qty value empty so I can have the user input it though a `<form>`, but I will figure that out once I find a form that fits what I need.

Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

I just need a look at the kind of array I need and if I will be able to apply it to my code and figure out the  and `action=POST` code later.

Comment: not clear what you're asking, but as I understood, an array that holds the objects would suffice, or an associative array if you want to have some keys related to the array apart from those that the objects already have.

Comment: Hmm let me see if i cant make it more clear, i have 3 product, movie1, movie2 and movie 3, when a users is looking at the product they can click buy if they want, and enter a value for quantity. So i would need a array on my cart page that can hold the movie id, price, and qty that was just submitted (the id and price will be static values) something like: array[0[ will hold $id=MO1, $qty=, $price=20, then array[1] will have $id=MO2, $qty=, $price=50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can handle this in php (server side) which is more common, and also you can handle in client side with java-script which i do'nt recommand .
you can use key-value arrays in php, for example you can easily do as bellow:

```
$basket[0]['productName']='Movies1';
$basket[0]['qty']=1;
$basket[0]['price']=15;
$basket[1]['productName']='Movies2';
$basket[1]['qty']=2;
$basket[1]['price']=30;
```

in this way you will have an array which can hold all off required information about your products.

Comment: oh thanks, would this also work if i left the qty value empty then figured out a way to have it entered via a form?

Comment: yes sir, php arrays are really flexible. you can fill it with numbers or even leave it null, whenever you need you can fill it with required data